Using reCaptchaV3 token generated by PyPasser still results in authentication errors
I'm trying to authenticate with a website using Python's requests library, and the site uses reCAPTCHA v3 for login. I attempted to use the pypasser library to generate a valid reCAPTCHA token, but I keep receiving a 401 Unauthorized error when making the POST request.
Here’s my code:
import requests
from pypasser import reCaptchaV3

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Authorization": "",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Origin": "https://public.txdpsscheduler.com",
    "Referer": "https://public.txdpsscheduler.com/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
}


reCaptcha_response = reCaptchaV3(
    "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/anchor?ar=1&k=6LesF7oaAAAAAEvJD0hjmTUib8Q5PGjTo54U2ieP&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMudHhkcHNzY2hlZHVsZXIuY29tOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=EGbODne6buzpTnWrrBprcfAY&size=invisible&cb=n3itz0yfg7ny"
)

json_data = {
    "UserName": "username",
    "RecaptchaToken": {"Action": "login", "Token": reCaptcha_response},
}

response = requests.post("https://apptapi.txdpsscheduler.com/api/auth", headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False)

print(response.json())

This is the website I'm trying to login into: https://public.txdpsscheduler.com
Despite successfully generating a token using pypasser, I keep getting a 401 response from the server.


Please check pypassser source. recaptchaV3 is updated a lot, so it is impossible to bypass with this library.
Simple method is to use third party service or to build own captcha harvester.

I've also tried to pass the auth token from dev tools that generated when I logged into the website. But that does not work either.
